# laravel url /delete/id will delete a comment, need it to be disabled

Tags: php, laravel, url, sql-delete

I can delete comments when i type this in the url.. /delete/{id} from the comment. I need that to be private/disabled.

Route:

```
Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'commentController@delete');
```

controller:

```
function delete($id)
{
    comment::where('id',$id)->delete();
    return back();
}
```

view:

```
<a href="/delete/{{ $comment->id}}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Your problem is that any user can delete comments by typing the url?

Comment: What do you mean by `private/disabled` ??

Comment: encrypt the $id

Comment: @user2963176 yes thats the problem, even if you are not the admin.

Comment: then add a middleware to just admins like [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/create-middleware-to-auth-admin-users?page=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to show delete comment links only for comment owner

so in your view you should have if condition

for example:

```
@if (Auth::user() && (Auth::user()->id == $comment->user_id))
    <a href="/delete/{{ $comment->id}}">   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</button></a>
@endif
```

in this condition comment delete link only display for comment owner $comment->user_id is comment owner id that i dont know how you store it in your database

of course you should check it in you controller too like this:

```
{
if (Auth::user() && (Auth::user()->id == $comment->user_id)) {
    comment::where('id',$id)->delete();
    return back();
}else
return 'you dont have permission';
}
```

and if you want to limit it only for admin , in condition you should check user is admin like this:

```
Auth::user()->id == [admin_id]
```

OR
define a admin role and check

```
Auth::user()->role == 'admin'
```

Don't remember to study [form-method-spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing) to choose best way to delete data in your database

Comment: The if statement worked for me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You should *not* be able to delete *anything* in your application using a GET request, i.e. by visiting a URL. What happens if Google finds these links a crawls them? It’s then going to initiate delete requests, and your users are going to be angry.

Instead, items should be deleted by making a DELETE request (or a POST request with a hidden `_method` parameter with the value of `DELETE`), and then also protected by authentication, and optional authorisation (to determine *which* users can delete the given resource).

If you use Laravel’s resource controllers, it will set this route up for you. Running `php artisan make:controller CommentController --resource --model=Comment` will create a controller with actions for your `Comment` model, such as creating, editing, and deleting. You then want to apply the `auth` middleware to at least your `destroy()` action, and if only specific users should be able to delete specific comments, then you need to look at [authorisation using policies](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a middleware for admin users and then in your controller construtor you only need to do something like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin')->only('delete');
}
```

You can read more about middleware [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)